# Не подгружается скрипт в Ajax форме

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Итак, попытаюсь объяснить суть проблемы :) 
Вот сайт `https://filmoteka.com.ua/index`
На главной странице выводятся данные о фильме, получение информации происходит через Ajax-запрос к файлу `randfilm.php`, откуда информация выводится через `echo()`.

Под списком актёров должен выводиться рейтинг в виде звёздочек, но он не подгружается (в этом суть проблемы). Я никак не могу разобраться, в чём проблема, ведь если выводить данные не через Ajax, а прямо через файл главной страницы, то звездочки работают.
Прилагаю часть кода:
Файл главной страницы, здесь важен только последний div, в него выводится Ajax запрос:

```
<php  
echo '
        <div class="catMenuRand">
            <form method="POST" id="find-rand" onsubmit="changeRand()" action="javascript:void(null);">
                <select size="1" name="randcat">
                   ...здесь перечень категорий...
                </select>
                <div class="catYear">
                   ...здесь инпуты для диапазона годов...
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Знайти фільм">
            </form>
        </div><br>
    ';

    echo '<div id="rand-film" class="rand-film"></div>';

?>
```

Файл `randfilm.php` это файл-обработчик запроса:

```
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `films` WHERE `active` = 1 AND (`date` >= $_POST[rangeFor] AND `date` <= $_POST[rangeTo]) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"));
echo '

                <span class="rand-film-title"><a href="/material/film/id/'.$Row['id'].'">'.$Row['name'].'</a></span>
                <div class="rand-film-poster">
                    <img src="/resource/poster/'.$Row['dir'].'/'.$Row['id'].'.jpeg">';

                    if ($Row['original_name']) echo '<span style="color: #d8d8d8">Авторська назва: </span>'.$Row['original_name'].'<br>';
                    echo '
                    <span style="color: #d8d8d8">Жанр: </span>'.$category.'<br>
                    <span style="color: #d8d8d8">Рік: </span>'.$Row['date'].'<br>
                    <span style="color: #d8d8d8">Країна: </span>'.$Row['country'].'<br>
                    <span style="color: #d8d8d8">Тривалість: </span>'.$Row['lenght'].' хв.<br>
                    <span style="color: #d8d8d8">Режисер: </span>'.$Row['director'].'<br>
                    <span style="color: #d8d8d8">В ролях: </span>'.$role.'<br>
                    <div id="rating">
                        <input type="hidden" name="val" value="'.$Row['total_value'].'">
                        <input type="hidden" name="votes" value="'.$Row['total_votes'].'">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$Row['vote_id'].'">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="rand-film-description">'.$Row['description'].'</span>

        ';
```

И файл footer.php где я подключаю скрипты:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/js/jquery.rating-2.0.js"></script>

<script>

  function showRand() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/page/randfilm.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#rand-film").html(html);
      }
    });          
  }

  function changeRand() {
    var msg = $('#find-rand').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/page/randfilm.php",
      data: msg,
      success: function(html) {
        $('#rand-film').html(html);
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    showRand();
    $('#rating').rating({
      fx: 'half',
          image: '/resource/img/stars.png',
          loader: '/resource/img/ajax-loader.gif',
          minimal: 1,
      url: '/rating.php'
    });
  });

</script>
```

Итак, объясняю, почему вызов Ajax делаю дважды: первый раз выводим данные о случайном фильме при загрузке страницы, а второй вызов делаем уже с данными из формы, если пользователь ищет по определённой категории или году.
Также хочу добавить: если вывод делать из главной страницы (содержимое echo из файла `randfilm.php` перенести в блок `rend-film`), то звёздный рейтинг работает (он выводится в блоке #raiting). Если объяснил не внятно то прошу уточнить.
Сам плагин рейтинга взят из сайта `https://biznesguide.ru/coding/156.html`

На моём сайте он ещё подключён на полной странице фильма, и там прекрасно работает, а почему вот почему не работает на главной - не понятно :(((

Comment: А что за /raring.php? С путями точно все верно?

Comment: Только заметил, в document.ready вы используете аякс сначала а потом рейтинг подключаете. Попробуйте в document.ready оставить только showRand, а функцию для рейтинга вложите в success самого showRand

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, и теперь рейтинг отображается, но плагин рейтинга почему то не передает данные обработчику результата (файл rating.php обрабатывает и вносит результат в БД). Плагин должен высчитывать число звезд при голосовании и передавать POST запрос результата обработчику, после этого обработчик вносит изменения в БД и возвращает json ответ результата операции типа ОК или ERR, и если ОК по виставляет закрашенными некое количество звезд, но почему то POST запрос не доходит до обработчика.